# Elasticsearch Nest Query Filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, elasticsearch, nest

I want to get records through filter.

**Sql Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM testdb  Where contactId = "e84aca88-7b82-43d9-8788-4cc25af0c43a"
```

Json Query :

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 200,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "query": {
                            "match": {
                                "contactId": {
                                    "query": "e84aca88-7b82-43d9-8788-4cc25af0c43a",
                                    "type": "phrase"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i search with this query by nest?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to convert the above query to Nest query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong. It should work like this:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 200,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "contactId": "e84aca88-7b82-43d9-8788-4cc25af0c43a"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Before you copy and paste, please look at this queries format and read up about the `bool` query and using `match`:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Also, checkout the Inquisitor plugin for Elasticsearch, this will help you to build your queries and test queries formats:

https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor

Answer (score 0):

I want to work Nest with C# like this query

```
client.Search<Contact>(s => s.Query(q => q.Term(p => p.ContactId, "e84aca88-7b82-43d9-8788-4cc25af0c43a")));
```

so I have to turn the json query to Nest query